# How to update Jade file css, js references by grunt-usemin

Tags: express, pug, gruntjs

My app uses a `jade` templates which is served by NodeJS `express` framework. It uses `grunt` to build the front end. I found that `grunt-usemin` creates grunt configurations for tasks such as `uglify`, `concat`, `cssmin` and `requirejs` and it also updates the `css`, `js` references in the end.

The `grunt-usemin` works very well with HTML files. I also found that `grunt-contrib-jade` plugin useful when we compiles jade to html. But I do not want to compile jade to HTML files.

How can i use `grunt-usemin` with jade templates or any other solutions to do it?

Comment: Did you get this figured out? I can't seem to get `usemin-patterns` to work correctly and it's not well documented at this point.

Comment: What's in your `jade` template?

Comment: Any luck with this? I'm also having issues...

Comment: Try this one.
https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-jade-usemin

Comment: I was actually able to solve this with `usemin-patterns` (linked below) and by adding new functionality to `grunt-usemin`. See this pull request here: https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin/pull/380

Answer (score 7):

You could use [usemin-patterns](https://github.com/bevacqua/usemin-patterns)

```
usemin: {
    jade: 'src/views/**/*.jade',
    options: {
        assetsDirs: ['public'],
        patterns: {
            jade: require('usemin-patterns').jade
        }
    }
}
```